# How to find right properties in the array with objects (arrange by age)?

Tags: javascript

## Declare massive with objects and console log the different people according to their Age.

```
var people = [
        { firstname: 'Gosho', lastname: 'Petrov', age: 42 },
        { firstname: 'Bay', lastname: 'Ivan', age: 81 },
        { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe', age: 42 },
        { firstname: 'Pesho', lastname: 'Pesho', age: 22 },
        { firstname: 'Asdf', lastname: 'Xyz', age: 81 },
        { firstname: 'Gosho', lastname: 'Gosho', age: 22 }
    ];
    
    
    var counter=0;
    for(i=0; i<people.lenght; i+=1) {
        if (people[i].age === people[i+1].age) {
            counter+=people[i];
        }
    }
```

How can i arrange the people by Age and console log them.

Comment: your for loop has a typo. lenght should be length. and instead of `i+=1` you could do `i++`

Comment: i fixed the  typo issue but still there is error: ypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var people = [{ firstname: 'Gosho', lastname: 'Petrov', age: 42 }, { firstname: 'Bay', lastname: 'Ivan', age: 81 }, { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe', age: 42 }, { firstname: 'Pesho', lastname: 'Pesho', age: 22 }, { firstname: 'Asdf', lastname: 'Xyz', age: 81 }, { firstname: 'Gosho', lastname: 'Gosho', age: 22 }];

people.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.age - b.age; // ascending
});

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lodash` `sortBy()` method.

https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];

_.sortBy(users, [function(o) { return o.age; }]);
```

this will returns sorted new array

```
[['barney', 34], ['barney', 36], ['fred', 40], ['fred', 48]]
```